# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied while opening mp3 file from MusicLibrary Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I try to open mp3 files from foreground using SetUriSource, but I keep getting :

```
Failed with error code System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I already define the music library cappability and set .mp3 file type on declaration. I have a Windows Runtime Component with a class inside, and I call this method from that class.

```
 var mediaPlayer = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
 var folder = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFolderAsync("myFolder");
 StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("myFile.mp3");
 mediaPlayer.AutoPlay = true;
 mediaPlayer.SetUriSource(new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Here is the file.Path result i got :

```
C:\Data\Users\Public\Music\myFolder\myFile.mp3
```

how to fix this problem ? thank you

Comment: Have you set permissions? Also, have tried to run the app as Admininstrator?

Comment: I set the permission on package.appxmanifest for music library and removable storage, I read that the only way to access the file from foreground and attach it to background media player is by using SetUriSource, but it keeps giving me that error

Comment: Open the visual studio as Administrator.

Comment: @Chandru Title was modified and it says that it happens on WP8.1 so VS rights do not matter during debugging.

Comment: I tried Uri from other source and it works without error, it only happen in KnownFolders....

Answer (score 0):

I found that not possible for now to execute the

```
var mediaPlayer = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
var folder = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFolderAsync("myFolder");
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("myFile.mp3");
mediaPlayer.AutoPlay = true;
mediaPlayer.SetUriSource(new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

from foreground, so I execute this line of code from BackgroundTask class and it works. thx